# Ошибка при запуске сборки файла .exe

Tags: c++, qt

Получилось доделать проект на C++ в qt, очень нужна помощь

сборка прошла отлично, никаких нет ошибок, файл Kurs.exe сгенерировался, но выдает такие ошибки при открытии, помогите пожалуйста[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужные DLL-библиотеки либо отсутствуют (что вряд ли...), либо каталоги с ними не указаны в переменной окружения `PATH`.

Comment: http://blog.harrix.org/article/1015#h2_2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё намного проще, чем вам кажется. Вам нужно открыть путь к компилятору QT, в моём случае это

> C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013_64\bin

Найдите в этом пути

> windeployqt.exe

После откройте ваш с build`женный проект, а именно Kurs.exe. Теперь откройте cmd и пропишите туда следующее

> C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013_64\bin\windeployqt.exe <Ваш путь до файла>\Kurs.exe

Стоит отметить, что виндеплой подтянет все нужные либы, используемые в проекте. P.s. пути до Qt у нас с вами отличаются.

Answer (score 0):

Путь к libstdc ++ - 6.dll в переменной среды PATH?
Я думаю, что DLL находится в C:\qt\mingw64\bin

В консоли введите:

```
@set path@
```

если путь к DLL отсутствует в списке, введите:

```
@set path = C:\qt\mingw64\bin;% PATH%@
```

Теперь попробуйте qmake снова.